# Select ComboBoxItem based on its tag value

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox

My ComboBoxItems have string values that represent the name of the item to be selected, but I've stored the value for that item in `Tag` property of the `ComboBoxItem`. I use the `Tag` as the asp.net equivalent to the dropdownlist Item `Value`.

In the code behind where I set the datagrid template column, I set the `ComboBoxItem` as follows:

```
<ComboBoxItem Tag='" + product.ProductGuid + "' Content='" + product.Name + "'></ComboBoxItem>
```

I need to programmatically select a `ComboBoxItem` based on the `Tag` value not the content. In the code below, `currentProduct` holds the ProductGuid value that I need to select, but this code will select the `ComboBoxItem` whose Content is my `currentProduct`

```
((ComboBox)QuotationDG.Columns[0].GetCellContent(MyData[MyData.Count - 1])).SelectedValue = currentProduct;
```

Is there a way to set the `ComboBox` Selected value to the `ComboBoxItem` whose Tag value is `currentProduct`?

EDIT:

Here's the code I use to bind my ComboBox Column:

```
private string CreateDDLColumnEditTemplate(int index, string propertyName, List<Product> ProductList)
        {
            StringBuilder CellTemp = new StringBuilder();
            CellTemp.Append("<DataTemplate ");
            CellTemp.Append("xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/");
            CellTemp.Append("2006/xaml/presentation' ");
            CellTemp.Append("xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>");
            CellTemp.Append(String.Format("<ComboBox SelectedValue='{{Binding [{0}], Mode=TwoWay}}'>",0));
            foreach (Product product in ProductList)
            {
                CellTemp.Append("<ComboBoxItem Tag='"+product.ProductGuid+"' Content='" + product.Name + "'></ComboBoxItem>");
            }
            CellTemp.Append(String.Format("</ComboBox>"));
            CellTemp.Append("</DataTemplate>");
            return CellTemp.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Did either of these answers work for you?

Comment: What you are looking for is `ComboBox.SelectedValuePath` and `ComboBox.SelectedValue`. These two combined will do what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is

```
YourComboBox.SelectedValue = currentProduct
```

and

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" etc. etc. etc. />
```

which means your `SelectedValue` gets its value from your `Tag`

Answer (score 2):

The use of the combobox has the ability bind to objects and specify what is to be displayed in the dropdown. Why not use the `Product` object which you are loading into the tag but show something different on the drop down?

If need be create an extended, `Partial` object, to display something wholly different in the drop down, but **still access** the `Product` item to change the selection.

---

The suggestion here is to simply bind the combobox to the `Product` data item. Then you can change the value dynamically without using the `Tag` property.

For example I have this data type similar to your Product type:

```
public class PriceItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the data list of values which is saved on my VM as `Items`.

```
Items = new List<PriceItem>()
{
    new PriceItem() { Name = "Alpha", Price=100 },
    new PriceItem() { Name = "Beta",  Price=200 },
};
```

**Scenario**
Two combo boxes, both bound to the `Items` data. One combo box shows the `Name` in its dropdown while the other shows the `Price`. The `Name` combobox controls the price combo box, when it changes the price changes as well.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboName" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<ComboBox x:Name="comboValue"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Price"
            SelectedValuePath="Price"
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.Price, ElementName=comboName, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

In action both combo boxes are blank. But whenever I select the first one it changes the second. All using the same data/data objects.

[image]

Comment: That sounds like the optimum answer, except that for my case, it's very complicated and I'm not sure if i can apply that solution. The combobox exists in a Datagrid column. The datagrid columns are loaded dynamically and the datasource is an observablecollection<Object[]>, the object[] holds the string data for each row. And finally, I'm binding the controls in my datagrid columns using the column index.

Comment: I've updated my question with a sample code of how I bind my ComboBox in the code behind